# Bad array new length error unhandled exception

Tags: c++, arrays, assignment-operator, unhandled-exception

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this.

I have a Movie.h with all the data members and constructors destructors and copy constructors needed but I have a feeling it's failing at my assignment operator someone, please help

```
  Movie& Movie::operator=(const Movie& _assign) {
    // Self-assignment check
    if (this == &_assign)
        return *this;

    // Shallow copy non-dynamic data members
    mRuntime = _assign.mRuntime;

    // Deep copy appropriate data members
    mTitle = new char[strlen(_assign.mTitle) + 1];
    strcpy_s(mTitle, strlen(_assign.mTitle) + 1, _assign.mTitle);

    // Deep copy the reviews
    SetStars(_assign.mStars, mNumReviews);

    return *this;
  }

  void Movie::SetStars(const int* _stars, int _numReviews) {
    
    // Allocate array and deep copy
    mStars = new int[_numReviews];

    for (int i = 0; i <= _numReviews; ++i) {
        // Cap reviews between 1-10
        if (_stars[i] > 10)
        {
            mStars[i] = 10;
        }
        else if (_stars[i] < 0)
        {
            mStars[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            mStars[i] = _stars[i];
        }
    }

    // Set the number of reviews
    mNumReviews = _numReviews;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using `char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: Unrelated: `mTitle` and `mStars` may have leaked pre-existing allocations. Obligatory link ot [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) Copy and Swap's not always the best solution, but it's next to impossible to get it wrong and makes an excellent starting point. Profiling the code will let you know if you need something more efficient.

Comment: You want to tell us what line of code your program is crashing? You want to tell us what the exact actual error message is? It's literally easier to copy and paste the error than to paraphrase it with fewer words.

Comment: no, I was hoping for someone to tell me why am I getting the error which line is causing the trouble

Comment: @Neteroh, please post the whole error message. And if you insist on not using a debugger, place some `cout` statements on EVERY LINE in your program and tell us after which `cout` your program crashes. This is called "print debugging", and is generally frowned upon, because it requires an absurd amount of program modification. Or, you could use a debugger.

Comment: This is the error message im getting @MPops:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAB8ABA799 in Debugging.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_array_new_length at memory location 0x0000008A3D9CEEB0.

Comment: it's been 3 hours. Have you learned how to use the debugger yet? Please tell us which line of code is causing this issue. Also, please update your original question with the code you said you have updated in other comments. If you don't do this, it's really hard to track what the problem with your code is. You said you changed something, so please update the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem happens here:

```
mStars = new int[_numReviews];


for (int i = 0; i <= _numReviews; ++i) {
```

Specifically here:

```
i <= _numReview // this causes you to go out of bounds
```

changing it to:

```
i < _numReview
```

resolves the issue

You are allocating `_numReview` items. C++ has 0-based array indexing. Elements will go from `0` to `_numReview - 1`

Please consider using `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of c-style arrays.

Comment: @Neteroh it will be better if you use std::string instead of the char array. I suspect that this line is causing the issue:  `strcpy_s(mTitle, strlen(_assign.mTitle) + 1, _assign.mTitle);` now.

Comment: I can't it's for an assignment which I'm not allowed to change that trust me I much rather work with strings than arrays

Comment: @Neteroh Run the program in the debugger that comes with your development environment. A decent debugger will stop dead as soon as the program crashes and allow you to inspect the crash site and the back trace that lead up to the crash. This will give you the information you need to narrow down the cause if not solve it outright.